# Datatables export pdf HTML message

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables 1.10 and would like to export PDF with **HTML** message. Because I need to include some specific info above the reports.
(Like date when report was made, who made the report etc.).

```
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        message: 'Made: 20_05-17<br />Made by whom? User232<br />'+this.messagePDF,
        title: title,
        header: true
    },
]
```

HTML in message isn't working, it just shows `<br />` tag.

Comment: It works fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/8qhu6xch/. Use `\n` instead of `<br>` to insert line-breaks.

Comment: For this one tip many thanks to you!! You saved my day!

Comment: But if I want add the <b> tags? and align so that one line would be in the middle-center and other would be like in your example?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply styles like bold, italics... to your text using doc.content.splice inside customize as shown in fiddle.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'pdfHtml5',
      //message: "Made: 20_05-17\nMade by whom: User232\n" + "Custom message",
      title: 'Export',
      header: true,
      customize: function(doc) {
        doc.content.splice(0, 1, {
          text: [{
            text: 'Made: 20_05-17 \n',
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 16
          }, {
            text: ' Made by whom: User232 \n',
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 11
          }, {
            text: 'Custom message',
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 11
          }],
          margin: [0, 0, 0, 12],
          alignment: 'center'
        });
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dbbybL80/